# Orbeon: use Autocomplete itemset in resource of another Autocomplete

Tags: xpath, httprequest, orbeon

I am using Orbeon Forms CE. How I can achieve this behavior:

In first resource type Autocomplete user can choose from few values requested from API, like '1 - aaa', '2 - bbb', '3 - ccc', where 'A' is code and 'aaa' is description - done.

In second resource type Autocomplete I would like to have values like 'X - xxx', 'Y - yyy', 'Z - zzz', where 'X' is code and 'xxx' is description. Values of this second autocomplete are based on mapping with the first one, like: '1: X, Y'; '2: Y, Z'; '3: X, Y, Z'. I can get the codes of this second Autocomplete by http request to API with code from first Autocomplete as parameter (for example sending '2' gives 'Y, Z' in response). But to get also descriptions ('yyy', 'zzz') I would need to send next request with 'Y, Z' as parameter.

So the question is: it is possible to take itemset of Autocomplete and put it in 'resource' attribute of another Autocomplete (as 'http...Y,Z...')? If yes, how to do that?

There is no posibility to make changes in used API.

---

**Update** to clear things up as Avernet suggested:

Yes, I can take the value selected in a 1st autocomplete, and put it in the resource URL for a 2nd autocomplete. But I want also: take all possible values of 2nd autocomplete and use them in URL for third Autocomplete.

Here is an life example:

We have a 3 tables: Books, Authors, and many-to-many Book-Authors.
Orbeon user chooses one Author in 1st autocomplete (which is using WS method on Authors table).
2nd autocomplete can be filled with **only ids** of books of choosen author (using WS method on Book-Authors table with 1st autocomplete value as argument). This autocomplete will be hidden.
In 3rd I want to have Books (with Titles) and it could be achieved if I can take all possible values of 2nd Autocomplete (using WS method on Books table with all values of 2nd autocomplete as argument).
Is this possible?

Disclaimers:

- API of WS is simple dictionary system and cannot be changed.
- autocompletes can be changed with databound-select1 components
- maybe final result can be achieved differently (e.g. without 2nd autocomplete), all suggestions are welcome

Comment: You can take the value selected in a 1st autocomplete, and put it in the `resource` URL for a 2nd autocomplete. Is this what you are looking for? If not, could you give a more realistic example of what you're looking for (not using 1, 2, x, y, but the real use case you are dealing with)? I think that would help us understand your situation. ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Kamil, have you found a way to pass the value to the other field? If not, could you share more details about your use case, per my previous message? ‑Alex

Comment: @avernet thank you for your answers and sorry for my late response. I have updated the question to make it more clear. Hope now you can help me.

Comment: Hi Kamil, are you saying that to populate the 3rd autocomplete, you'll need to make 1 web service call per book id in the 2nd autocomplete, to retrieve the information about that book? ‑Alex

Comment: Yes, that's right. 1st Autocomplete takes all authors, 2nd all books **ids** of chosen author and 3rd will have to take full info about books based on ids in 2nd autocomplete.

Comment: Sorry @evernet, I missunderstood last question so I update the answer: I need to take only one web service call with all books ids as parameters.

Comment: I think I got it, and posted an answer below. I hope this helps! ‑Alex

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the relevant part of your question, you have 3 services:

- *S1* returning a list of authors (name, id).
- *S2* taking an author id, returning list of book ids.
- *S3* taking a list of book ids, returning a list of book names.

You want to have 2 dropdowns:

- *D1* listing authors.
- *D2* listing the book names form the selected author.

First, I should note that instead of *S2* and *S3*, it would be better to have a single service that given an author id returns a list of books with their id and name. Assuming you have to deal with the services as-is, and can't create your own service on top of that, I would, in Form Builder, define:

- A service *OS1* for *S1*
- A field Hidden Field *OF1* that will hold the books ids for the selected author.
- An action *OA1*, which upon the value of the authors dropdown changing calls *OS1*, and populates *OF1* with a space separated list of book ids.
- A service *OS2* for *S2*.
- An action *OA2*, which upon the value of *OF1* changing calls *OS2*, passing the value of *OF1*, and using the result to populate the dropdown with the books.

Comment: Thank you, it should work in Orbeon Forms PE. Unfortunately I am using Orbeon Forms CE. Is there a solution for CE as well?

Comment: You're right, this requires the PE since it is using services and actions. Without using services and actions, one idea, which I think you already had, would be to use a hidden Dynamic Dropdown that contains the list of book ids. But that won't work, because you currently can't access the list of choices from a Dynamic Dropdown with XPath. So I think the best would be for you to create, with any technology you want, a "trampoline service" that combines S2 and S3 that takes an author id as input, and returns the list of books (name, id) written by this author. ‑Alex

Comment: Thank you again Alex. This is a valuable comment for me, as it ensures me that this is probably impossible to do that. Therefore I will request for a change on the service side.

Comment: Excellent, and I think this is best way to do it. (Even if you were using the PE, I'd recommend you do it this way.) ‑Alex